# How to use the full join in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I wants to join my two tables named inspector and detector having identical column Detection_ID using full join
I have used full outer join also but still same error is occuring.

Error message
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'inspector FULL JOIN detector ON inspector.D

And i am using the query.

'SELECT * inspector FULL JOIN detector ON inspector.Detection_ID = detector.Detection_ID;'

Is there any mistake in query or platform?

Comment: MySQL does not support `full join`. Please provide sample data and desired results so one can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB doesn't support `FULL JOIN`, as the error message suggests.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT i.*, d.*
FROM inspector LEFT JOIN
     detector d
    ON i.Detection_ID = d.Detection_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT i.*, d.*
FROM detector d LEFT JOIN
     inspector i
     ON i.Detection_ID = d.Detection_ID
WHERE i.Detection_ID IS NULL;
```

The first subquery gets all rows in `inspector`, regardless of whether or not there is a match in `detector`.  The second returns the rows in `detector` that are not in `inspector`.

That said, I would guess that column named `detection_ID` should have all valid values in `detector`.  That would suggest that a `FULL JOIN` is not necessary.